# ESLint правило убирающее точку с запятой

Tags: javascript, eslint

Необходимо в проекте убрать точку с запятой после строк.

В файле .eslintrc.js у меня прописано:

```
module.exports = {
rules: {
        semi: false
       }
  }
```

Так же продублировал в файл .prettierrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    semi: false
}
```

Запустил команду npx prettier --write . (тут все норм) потом запустил проект npm start и выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR

[eslint] .eslintrc.js:
    Configuration for rule "singleQuote" is invalid:
    Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed 'true').
```

В чем проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: Проблема в правиле `singleQuote`, явно же написано.

Comment: @OliverPatterson singleQuote это же правило ковычек. а мне нужна точка с запятой.

Могу предположить, что он типо ругается на то, что semi не возведены в кавычки, тогда возникает вопрос. Почему остальные исключения работают?

```
    rules: {
        indent: ['error', 4],
        singleQuote: true,
        jsxBracketSameLine: false,
        semi: false
    }
```
Да и код при сохранении у меня автоматом убирает кавычки везде.

Comment: У `singleQuote` не может быть значения `true`. Должно быть одно из этих значений (цифры): `0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error`

Comment: А, все понял. Не туда посмотрел. Просто по какой то причине он мне не выдает ошибку. Только когда semi ставлю. Вот я и подумал на него.